# XSLT nested lookup

Tags: xslt, lookup

New to XSLT, but have been learning a lot from posts here.  However, I'm stuck on one problem.

I am using XSLT to create a report for a device installation.  The input XML looks like this:

```
<DeviceTypes>
  <DeviceInfo Model="51473">
    <Channels>
      <ChannelInfo ChannelId="1" IsImplemented="false" SampRateHardware="448" />
      <ChannelInfo ChannelId="2" IsImplemented="true" SampRateHardware="224" />
    </Channels>
  </DeviceInfo>
  <DeviceInfo Model="51474">
    <Channels>
      <ChannelInfo ChannelId="1" IsImplemented="true" SampRateHardware="448" />
      <ChannelInfo ChannelId="2" IsImplemented="true" SampRateHardware="224" />
    </Channels>
  </DeviceInfo>
</DeviceTypes>
<Installation>
  <InstalledDevice Serial="597657" Model="51473">
    <Channels>
       <InstalledChannel ChannelId="1" Name="foo" />
       <InstalledChannel ChannelId="2" Name="bar" />
    </Channels> 
  </InstalledDevice>
</Installation>
```

I want to only process the InstallChannel node if the corresponding ChannelInfo has an "IsImplemented" set to true.  By "corresponding" I mean I am looking for the ChannelInfo with the same ChannelId and the same Model under the parent node.  Note that channels with the same ChannelId may have different IsImplemented values depending on what device they are under.

I've been using  and the key() function to successfully lookup, but this nested lookup has me stumped.

Thanks,

*-Mat*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that using the templates makes for better readability/extendability:  The key is using the variable to be able to reference both the Model and the ChannelId for the ChannelInfo node in the xpath for the InstalledChannel, so start with the InstalledDevice, and work your way down the heirarchy

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//InstalledDevice"/>

<xsl:template match="//InstalledDevice">
   <xsl:variable name="model">
       <xsl:value-of select="@Model"/>
   </xsl:variable>

   <xsl:for-each select="Channels/InstalledChannel">
      <xsl:variable name="channelId">
         <xsl:value-of select="@ChannelId"/>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:if test="//DeviceInfo[@Model=$model]/Channels/ChannelInfo[@ChannelId=$channelId and @IsImplemented='true']">
         Processing Goes Here
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

So that we can preserve context of our model variable,  I moved the InstalledChannel processing into the same template, and added the for-each.  That way each InstalledChannel instance can be examined individually for whether it needs to be processed, and handled accordingly.

Comment: Thanks.  I think your are close.  Again, the trick is there may be multiple ChannelInfo with the same ChannelId under different DeviceInfo, and they will not necessarily all have the same IsImplemented.  I will update the example to illustrate this.

Comment: No problem, the same general concept still applies,  you just have to start a little higher up the tree, and your xpath becomes a bit more complicated.  (I updated my answer).

Comment: I think the problem now is that your variable "channelId" will grab the first InstalledChannel, but there may be more than one.  I was trying to keep my example simple.  I'll update again.  Thanks.

Comment: Updated again.  The key now was to add the for-each,  to handle multiple channels while the model remains constant.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a short and simple (no conditionals, no variables no `xsl:for-each`) solution using keys**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kCI-ByIdImpl" match="ChannelInfo"
  use="concat(@ChannelId,
              '+', @IsImplemented,
              '+', ../../@Model)"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
   "Installation/*/*
         /InstalledChannel
              [key('kCI-ByIdImpl',
                   concat(@ChannelId, '+true',
                          '+', ../../@Model)
                   )
              ]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML fragment** (wrapped into a single top element to be made a well-formed XML document):

```
<t>
    <DeviceTypes>
        <DeviceInfo Model="51473">
            <Channels>
                <ChannelInfo ChannelId="1" IsImplemented="false" SampRateHardware="448" />
                <ChannelInfo ChannelId="2" IsImplemented="true" SampRateHardware="224" />
            </Channels>
        </DeviceInfo>
        <DeviceInfo Model="51474">
            <Channels>
                <ChannelInfo ChannelId="1" IsImplemented="true" SampRateHardware="448" />
                <ChannelInfo ChannelId="2" IsImplemented="true" SampRateHardware="224" />
            </Channels>
        </DeviceInfo>
    </DeviceTypes>
    <Installation>
        <InstalledDevice Serial="597657" Model="51473">
            <Channels>
                <InstalledChannel ChannelId="1" Name="foo" />
                <InstalledChannel ChannelId="2" Name="bar" />
            </Channels>
        </InstalledDevice>
    </Installation>
</t>
```

**only the wanted `InstalledChannel` element is processed** (in this case simply copied to the output):

```
<InstalledChannel ChannelId="2" Name="bar"/>
```

**Explanation**: Appropriate use of a composite key.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
/Installation/InstalledDevice/Channels/InstalledChannel/[count(/DeviceTypes/DeviceInfo/Channels/ChannelInfo[@ChannelId = @ChannelId and @IsImplemented = 'true') = 1]
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't think that will work because there may be multiple ChannelInfo with the same ChannelId under different DeviceInfo, and they will not necessarily all have the same IsImplemented.